# Write a for loop to output the elements an array

Tags: java, arrays

Consider an array named `MyArray` that has the elements shown below:

```
double[] MyArray = {2.3, 3.5, 4.5, 5.0, 3.5, 0.2};
```

I want to implement a for loop to output the elements of the array.

Can anyone help me with that?
Thank you.

Comment: Please show at some effort and what have you done so far, it will make it much more likely to get an answer you want. StackOverflow is not a code writing service, though. BTW, welcome!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that the numbers are double:

```
for (double number : MyArray) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

So a complete working code would be:

```
public class IterateArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] MyArray = {2.3, 3.5, 4.5, 5.0, 3.5, 0.2};

        for (double number : MyArray) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in the instructor power point our professor gave us, there are some errors in his code. 
The code intended to store Strings into an array. 

String  MyArray=new MyArray(20);

MyArray[0]=”3.4”;

MyArray[1]=2;

MyArray[2]=”4.6”;

I guess MyArray[1]=2; is wrong, but professor told me there are more errors.
Can you help me out? Thank you.

Comment: You should really try to post this with a little bit more structure. First thing, post the code in a code block using ``` before and after the code. Then list what you exactly want to do, what you tried or found out, and then ask the precise question.